# Selenium 4: Chrome Node does not register correctly to the hub

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, kubernetes, openshift, selenium-grid

I have an Openshift 3 Cluster containing the two following containers: selenium-hub and selenium-node-chrome. Please see below the attached deployment and service yaml files.

**Hub Deployment:**

```
apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  labels:
    app: selenium-hub
    selenium-hub: master
  name: selenium-hub
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    type: selenium-hub
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        type: selenium-hub
      name: selenium-hub
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: 'selenium/hub:latest'
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: master
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4444
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 4442
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 4443
              protocol: TCP
  triggers:
    - type: ConfigChange
```

**Hub Service:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: selenium-hub
    selenium-hub: master
  name: selenium-hub
spec:
  ports:
    - name: selenium-hub
      port: 4444
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 4444
    - name: publish
      port: 4442
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 4442
    - name: subscribe
      port: 4443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 4443
  selector:
    type: selenium-hub
  type: ClusterIP
```

**Node Deployment:**

```
apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  labels:
    app: selenium-node-chrome
  name: selenium-node-chrome
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    browser: chrome
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-chrome
        browser: chrome
      name: selenium-node-chrome-master
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST
              value: selenium-hub
            - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT
              value: '4442'
            - name: SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT
              value: '4443'
            - name: SE_NODE_HOST
              value: node-chrome
            - name: SE_NODE_PORT
              value: '5555'
          image: 'selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-20211102'
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: master
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5555
              protocol: TCP
  triggers:
    - type: ConfigChange
```

**Node Service:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: selenium-node-chrome
  name: selenium-node-chrome
spec:
  ports:
    - name: node-port
      port: 5555
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5555
    - name: node-port-grid
      port: 4444
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 4444
  selector:
    browser: chrome
  type: ClusterIP
```

**My Issue:**
The hub and the node are starting, but the node just keeps sending the registration event and the hub is logging some infos, which i dont really understand. Please see the logs attached below.

**Node Log:**

```
Setting up SE_NODE_GRID_URL...
Selenium Grid Node configuration: 
[events]
publish = "tcp://selenium-hub:4442"
subscribe = "tcp://selenium-hub:4443"

[server]
host = "node-chrome"
port = "5555"
[node]
session-timeout = "300"
override-max-sessions = false
detect-drivers = false
max-sessions = 1

[[node.driver-configuration]]
display-name = "chrome"
stereotype = '{"browserName": "chrome", "browserVersion": "95.0", "platformName": "Linux"}'
max-sessions = 1

Starting Selenium Grid Node...
11:34:31.635 INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
11:34:31.643 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
11:34:31.774 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://selenium-hub:4442 and tcp://selenium-hub:4443
11:34:31.843 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
11:34:32.854 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Event bus ready
11:34:33.018 INFO [NodeServer.createHandlers] - Reporting self as: http://node-chrome:5555 
11:34:33.044 INFO [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Detected 1 available processors
11:34:33.115 INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding chrome for {"browserVersion": "95.0","browserName": "chrome","platformName": "Linux","se:vncEnabled": true} 1 times
11:34:33.130 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: name, relative, id
11:34:33.471 INFO [NodeServer$1.start] - Starting registration process for node id 2832e819-cf31-4bd9-afcc-cd2b27578d58
11:34:33.473 INFO [NodeServer.execute] - Started Selenium node 4.0.0 (revision 3a21814679): http://node-chrome:5555 
11:34:33.476 INFO [NodeServer$1.lambda$start$1] - Sending registration event...
11:34:43.479 INFO [NodeServer$1.lambda$start$1] - Sending registration event...
11:34:53.481 INFO [NodeServer$1.lambda$start$1] - Sending registration event...
```

**Hub Log:**

```
2021-12-07 11:14:22,663 INFO spawned: 'selenium-grid-hub' with pid 11
2021-12-07 11:14:23,664 INFO success: selenium-grid-hub entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
11:14:23.953 INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
11:14:23.961 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
11:14:24.136 INFO [BoundZmqEventBus.<init>] - XPUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4442, advertising as tcp://XXXXXXX:4442], XSUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4443, advertising as tcp://XXXXXX:4443]
11:14:24.246 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://XXXXXX:4442 and tcp://XXXXXXX:4443
11:14:24.275 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
11:14:25.278 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Event bus ready
11:14:26.232 INFO [Hub.execute] - Started Selenium Hub 4.1.0 (revision 87802e897b): http://XXXXXXX:4444 
11:14:46.965 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: name, relative, id
11:15:46.916 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: relative, name, id
11:17:52.377 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: relative, id, name
```

Can anyone tell me why the hub wont register the node?
If you need any further informations, let me know.
Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, bit late, but still I had this same issue - the `docker-compose` example gave me selenium-hub as the host, which is correct in that scenario as it points towards the container defined by the selenium-hub service.
However, in Kubernetes, the inter-pod communication needs to go via a Service. There are multiple kinds of Service, but in order to access it from inside the cluster, it's easiest in this case to use a ClusterIP ([docs here for more info](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)).

The way I resolved it was to have a Service for both the ports that the event bus uses:

- bus-publisher (port 4442)
- bus-subscription (port 4443)

In a manifest yaml, this looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app-name: selenium
  name: bus-sub
  namespace: selenium
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 4443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4443
  selector:
    app: selenium-hub
  type: ClusterIP
```

Comment: This sounds like a good idea to me. Sadly, I'm not able anymore to test this fix since this project has been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

You are in same machine so I think you don't need to use the environment variable: SE_NODE_HOST in the node deployment only use these variables:

```
SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
```

If you think you aren't in the same VM, you need to config the node deployment correctly by using these environment variables :

```
SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=<ip-of-hub-machine>
SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
SE_NODE_HOST=<ip-of-node-machine>
```

Please don't add unused environment variables like:'SE_NODE_PORT' because selenium image doesn't support different environment variables besides the environment variables you can read in the documents in Github 'docker-selenium' project: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium.
If you are so much want to use your variable. So create your own selenium image (I don't recommend that) I succuss with what I say to you.

Comment: Node and host are not in the same machine, as they run on an openshift cluster in different pods. The IPs aren't directly referred, but openshift resolves them by using just the selector like "node-chrome".

Answer (score -1):

you didn't expose the ports 4443 and 4442 from the hub container (see ports section of spec.containers)

Comment: I have added  the ports as containerPorts to the ports section in the hub yaml file. The results are the same as before

Comment: Did you restart all the pods to take the new configuration?

Comment: Sure, I tried different configurations and always restarted the pods.

Comment: do you have any firewall in place? how did you set up the infrastructure for the cluster? do you have any network policies in place?

Comment: We do have firewalls, but only for external traffic. Inside our OC namespace, there shouldnt be any of them. The infrastructure is setup by a central team, i didnt interfere with that. I dont have any network policies

Comment: I'd try to put them both on the same node, next option check from the containers terminal (from GUI or CLI) if the're pingable from each other, next if you have any networking tool on the containers like telnet, curl... I'd try to check that higher level of communications. please report back with any results you're getting